# Is there a way to Chrome command-line argument that it will use a local file as a CA (cert authority) for that session only?

Tags: openssl

Let's say I've created a local private CA (with OpenSSL) (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516812/8679778).  I can use it from a client application that uses https to a server running on the same computer, using a cert from the same locally created CA.
But what if I want Chrome to have the same capability.   I know I can register the CA with the local root store, but I don't want to affect the entire system -- just a specific invocation of the browser.